# VueJS Number Formats real time seperate by comma when Input Intl.NumberFormat

Tags: javascript, vue.js, number-formatting

I'm a beginner and I want to display Currency sign and seperate using comma when inserting the number input at the same time. I wrote this as I understand. So far no good. Anyone knows how ? Thanks

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input
      type="text"
      id="cost"
      v-model="cost"
      @input="dd"
      name="cost"
      class="form-control form-control-md"
      placeholder="Enter cost of construction"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      cost: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    dd() {
      var number = this.cost;

      new Intl.NumberFormat("en-EN", {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "USD",
      }).format(number);

      return number;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, a little late.

This is actually a crappy 5-min-put-together implementation of what you want to achieve. There are much better solutions out there and if you start using this, you'll soon notice its flaws.

But it should get you starting and help you get the gist of it.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      cost: 0,
      formatLang: 'en-EN',
      formatStyle: 'currency',
      formatCurrency: 'USD'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    formatter() {
      return new Intl.NumberFormat(this.formatLang, {
        style: this.formatStyle,
        currency: this.formatCurrency
      })
    },
    formattedCost() {
      return this.formatter.format(this.cost)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}

label input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label @click="$refs.numberInput.focus()">
    <input ref="numberInput" type="number" v-model="cost" />
    <div class="formatted">{{ formattedCost }}</div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a method.

```
  dd()
        {
            if (this.cost != '') {
                var num = this.cost;
                
                

               num =  new Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN',  {
                    style: 'currency',
                    currency: 'USD',
                    }).format(num);
                        
                this.cost = num;
            }
        }
```

Now after input it shows currency symbol and separate using commas. One problem is when editing input value It shows `NaN` otherwise It's fine . Tell me if anyone know how to resolve that issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your problem is that you try to use a formatted number (string) as a number again. `Number('USD 123.45')` will return `NaN` because it cannot convert `'USD'` to a number. You need 2 variables. The actual `num` (e.g. `this.numCost`) and the formatted string representation of `num` => `this.cost`. Then you have to use `this.numCost` in `Intl.NumberFormat`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did understand some points. Earlier the cost data  property displayed as '10000' but now it shows '$10000.00' . So it cannot be saved into database as decimal value .Because I assigned the value to v-model. Could you please explain me by writing the code If you got time. Thank you very much